# openid service .well-known/openid-configuration not reachable after installing ADFS on windows server 2019

Tags: openid, adfs, windows-server, openiddict

I created a service with OpenIDDict and .Net6, everything was working fine and the url https://auth.myserver.local/.well-known/openid-configuration, served with IIS, was working correctly.

I wanted to add an SSO service and loggin in with my AD user, so I followed this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I installed the ADFS service on my server (the same server of IIS) and I was able to sign in.

Then I noticed that If I go to the main page of my service (https://auth.myserver.local) the service still works great, but if I try to reach https://auth.myserver.local/.well-known/openid-configuration I receive a 503 error - service unavailable.

I've made some research in IIS logs but I cannot find requests on that url anymore, It seems something is getting the request before IIS.

I tried to stop the ADFS service with no success.

Anyone experienced something similar?
My server is Windows Server 2019.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution!

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/iisadmin-service-inetinfo/httpsys-registry-windows

It seems there are reserved url on windows registry. If there's a filter here, the request doesn't reach IIS.

you can check them with this command:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

I found the /.well-known/ filter on port 433 at the following path:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\UrlAclInfo

Removing it, everything started again.
This was set up by Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS), wich was installed for test purpose and then uninstalled.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to enable endpoint url and Proxy.

To set an EndPoint:

```
Set-AdfsEndpoint -TargetAddressPath "/adfs/services/trust/13/Windows" -Proxy $True
```

You can follow this article from MS Docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsendpoint?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: thank you for comment, I tried adding the address path as my endpoint (https://auth.myserver.local/.well-known/openid-configuration) but I get an error: No Endpoint found with Address https://auth.myserver.local/.well-known/openid-configuration. I'm still confused about that... Can you please explane better? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are still missing /adfs before /.well-known.
It should be like this https://yourServer/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration.
When you add a path it starts with /adfs.... and when you want to access the Metadata it should include the FQDN before the endpoint with the https.

Comment: It's not working. But I think you missed out I need to reach not the ADFS .well-known endpoint, but my custom Identity server .well-known
So it's a totally different path instead of the ADFS one.